# How to update multiple fields which including related fields of a django model instance?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering, what is a standard way of updating multiple fields which includes related fields of an instance of a model in django? ...

```
Class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
    dob = models.CharField()

Class Appointment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    app_id = models.CharField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField()
```

To update multiple fields in appointment model I could just do

```
dict ={
"app_id": "123",
"time": "2012-01-01 10:30",
"status": "Open"
}
Appointment.objects.filter(app_id=123).update(dict)
```

Is there a way to update the related model?
How could I do an update on Appointment model and User Model? 
Case:

```
dict ={
"name": "foo",
"app_id": "123",
"time": "2012-01-01 10:30",
"status": "Open"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For clarity's sake - that's not what 'inherited' means.  Appointment is related to user, but does not inherit from it.

The update method on the queryset can't do this in a single call.  The docs say:

> the only restriction on the QuerySet that is updated is that it can only update columns in the model’s main table, not on related models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update

If you have the app_id and nothing else, you can write a second update call:

```
User.objects.filter(appointment__app_id=123).update(name='foo')
```

Comment: Is it possible to overcome this restriction using SQL?

Comment: @shpindler - I can't think of a way offhand, each SQL update statement updates records in a single table so to update two tables you're looking at two updates.