# How to update fields of related model in one query using Django ORM or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, bulkupdate

I want to update model fields and fields of related model in one query in Django:

```
Link.objects.filter(alpha=True).update(
    alpha=False,
    target__backup_of_original_start=F('target__original_start'),
    target__backup_of_original_end=F('target__original_end'),
    target__original_start=F('target__start'),
    target__original_end=F('target__end'),
)
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571151/10780812) I see that it is impossible using `update`. Is it possible to overcome this restriction using Django ORM or at least plain SQL? And how?

Comment: Is it mandatory to be in just one update?

Comment: @bdbd any suggestions to minimize db queries are welcome

Comment: In Django ORM, everything you do is centered on only one model, avoiding kraken-style work.  I suggest to stick to that style (which is nice for understandability) as long as you can. Only search for alternatives if your query really turns out to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score -1):

You can create SQL Stored Procedures and SQL Views to make only one DB request.

Helpful resource:
[What is the best way to access stored procedures in Django's ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805393/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-stored-procedures-in-djangos-orm)